# "ActionView::Template::Error (Ruby statement not allowed" on iteration using ERB_LINT ruby on rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3, rubocop

After install and use successfully rubocop I noticed that rubocop does not act on .html.erb files.

So I found **erb_lint** gem, and despite does not have a friendly integration into Sublimetext, and is not fully integrated into rubocop as I thought, I managed to get it working.

Not sure if is the right way: To get errors, I have to run the server `rails s`, and if an error is found, the application crash and in console I can see the errors.
The problem is in this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Ruby statement not allowed.
In 'quoted_value' on line 188 column 0:
<%                 company.families.ordered.each do |f| 

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^):
```

and here it is my line 188 (and more)

```
<% company.families.ordered.each do |f| %>
```

[image]

what's wrong on that? Why is this ruby statement not allowed?

I suppose everyone has iterations on ruby on rails views

--------------- 17-10-2018 - updated, still with same error in an earlier line

After fixing " and ' and spaces... as erb_lint asks for, and using *html_attributes* helper as it asks too, I'm still with the same error:.

What's wrong with this?:

```
  <% data_body_bg_imgs=data_body_bg() %>
  <body
    <% data_body_bg_imgs.each do |img_hash| %>
      <%= html_attributes(img_hash) %>
    <% end %>
    data-menu-bg-color="<%= preference.menu_bg_color %>"
    data-theme="<%= preference.theme %>"
    data-cap-opacity="<%= preference.menu_opacity %>"
```

What I do, is very simply: store a array of hashes in `data_body_bg_imgs` and then, in an iteration I populate `data` attributes of the `body` using the helper html_attributes

the error is

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Ruby statement not allowed.
In 'tag' on line 62 column 0:
<%     data_body_bg_imgs.each do |img_hash| 

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^):
```

in the line 62 there is `<% data_body_bg_imgs.each do |img_hash| %>`

Comment: Perhaps the real problem it's actually on line 190, which contains a variable assignment.

Comment: And, is not correct make assignments to variables in a html.erb file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [ERB Lint README](https://github.com/Shopify/erb-lint), it is run with the command `bundle exec erblint [options]` and not with `rails s`, so it looks like there is something wrong.

The `'quoted_value'` error could be related to using double quotes (`"`) for strings which do not have interpolation in lines 189 and 190.

Comment: Thanks, I will review and tell you as soon a retake the the issue

Comment: Yes that's right. And I have been using it. now I have no errors. Even Though it has been a little hard to use it, finally I used the --autocorrect option and git it. But erb_lint broke (ate) some code!!!

Comment: Still can't try because I have made to much changes in this branch. I will say if changing these " for ' does not produces errors on `rails server`

Comment: After fixing double quotes and spaces...etc , does not work. It seems erb_lint doesn't like iterations inside a html tag.